# Filter combobox list as you type Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

I've got the below code to filter a ComboBox list as you type.

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_KeyUp(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)

    Dim arrIn As Variant, arrOut As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long

    arrIn = Sheet1.Range("A2:G7")

    ReDim arrOut(1 To UBound(arrIn), 1 To 2)
    For i = 1 To UBound(arrIn)
        If arrIn(i, 1) Like ComboBox1.Text & "*" Then
            j = j + 1
            arrOut(j, 1) = arrIn(i, 1)
            arrOut(j, 2) = arrIn(i, 2)
        End If
    Next

    ComboBox1.List = arrOut

End Sub
```

However, I need to make changes the range for array as **Range("A2:A2000")** accordingly I also have to make some changes here as well **ReDim arrOut(1 To UBound(arrIn), 1 To 2)**.

I'm unable to understand as I'm bad in array concepts and modifying them. Can anyone can help me?

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly then the following code will place the values from `Range("A2:A2000")` into the array and then filter the ComboBox accordingly:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_KeyUp(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
    Dim arrIn As Variant, arrOut As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long

    arrIn = Sheet1.Range("A2:A2000")

    ReDim arrOut(1 To UBound(arrIn), 1 To 1)

    For i = 1 To UBound(arrIn)
        If arrIn(i, 1) Like ComboBox1.Text & "*" Then
            j = j + 1
            arrOut(j, 1) = arrIn(i, 1)
        End If
    Next
    ComboBox1.List = arrOut
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Xabier for your help :)
I'm getting Run time error 70 at ComboBox1.List = arrOut

Comment: @Linga I've tested this and it works as expected for me, error 70 refers to "Permission Denied" as when someone has a combo box with a rowsource value assigned - i.e. the combo box  is pointing to a range on the worksheet... and then you try to manually add to the combo box using the additem method. You can not have both a rowsource value and use additem at the same time. This occurs typically in the initialise event of the userform.

Comment: Oh yea that's right! However, i'm not getting the list into combo box for partially matched string. Anything else is wrong here?

Comment: @Linga the code does look for partial matches that begin with what the user typed on the ComboBox, if you also want matches that don't necessarily begin with the typed value, you can change `If arrIn(i, 1) Like ComboBox1.Text & "*" Then` to `If arrIn(i, 1) Like "*" & ComboBox1.Text & "*" Then`