# Filter Rowsource Combobox when typing Excel VBA

Tags: sql, excel, vba, user-controls

So I have been searching everywhere and tried numerous combinations but I can't seem to get this.

I have a user with a combo box called ***cboSearch***, the ***RowSource*** is set to ***=tblCustomers[FullName]***.

I am trying to filter the ***cboSearch*** ***RowSource*** according to what is entered into the search box while typing, just like you would filter in a worksheet table.

My worksheet is called ***CustomerList***
My table is called ***tblCustomers***
The column I'm trying to use and filter is ***FullName***

I have tried the following:

```
Private Sub cboSearch_Change()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("CustomerList")
    Set tbl = ws.ListObjects("tblCustomers")
    Set rng = tbl.ListColumns("FullName").Range
    
    Me.cboSearch.RowSource = "CustomerList!tblCustomers![No]"
    
End Sub
```

---

```
Private Sub cboSearch_Change()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("CustomerList")
    Set tbl = ws.ListObjects("tblCustomers")
    Set rng = tbl.ListColumns("FullName").Range
    
    Me.cboSearch.RowSource = rng
    
End Sub
```

---

```
Private Sub cboSearch_Change()

    Me.cboSearch.RowSource = "SELECT tblCustomers.FullName " & vbCrLf & _
                                "FROM tblCustomers " & vbCrLf & _
                                "WHERE (((tblCustomers.FullName) = [Forms]![CustomerForm]![cboSearch])) ;"
    
End Sub
```

---

I want the source to filter the results as I type and show the results as I type.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52051961/filter-combobox-list-as-you-type-excel-vba) had a similar issue wanting to filter as you type. As for the range, you'll probably want to use something [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62403096/19353309) answer with the UsedRange. Hope that helps a bit.

Comment: Need any further assistance?